# How to compare a long list of things with another long list of things without running out of memory?

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance

This is an R question but it could probably come up in any other (high-level) lang.

I have two sets of words. I want to know the distance between *each* word in set1 and *each* word in set2. And then count how many times a word in set1 has a distance of 1 wrt the words in set2.

The way I do this now is I make a massive table by crossing set1 and set2. This works up to a point but becomes memory-prohibitive with large sets. (I wind up with about 1e+9 combinations). Here's the idea:

```
strings1 = tibble::tibble(
  string1 = c(
    'apple',
    'orange',
    'pear',
    'kiwi'
  )
)

strings2 = tibble::tibble(
  string2 = c(
    'apple',
    'orange',
    'bear',
    'iwi'
  )
)

strings = tidyr::crossing( # problem #
  strings1,
  strings2
)

strings %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    lv = stringdist::stringdist(string1, string2, method = "lv")
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::count(
    string1, lv
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(lv == 1)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  word1    lv     n
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 kiwi      1     1
2 pear      1     1
```

Let's say I don't want to get access to more ram.

The way I would do this now is:

- write both sets out to memory
- use a shell script to chug through them in a couple years like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/753608/is-there-any-program-for-fuzzy-string-matching-which-provides-a-match-score).

But maybe there's a clever power user way to automate this / get round it? With indexing? And.. magic?

Comment: You can restrict your search space by first looking at the word lengths and only comparing words that differ in length by at most 1 character.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this:

```
strings1 %>%
  mutate(
    count = string1 %>% 
      map(~stringdist::stringdist(.x, strings2[["string2"]])) %>% 
      map_dbl(~sum(.x == 1))
  ) %>%
  filter(count > 0)
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  string1 count
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 pear        1
2 kiwi        1
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing out some tricks (like the one suggested by Bas) I ended up chopping up list1 into several bits and mapping the entire function to these separate bits. Didn't find a way to automate this without writing my own code tho.